# What kind of istinja is permissible in Islam?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, muslim-practices

I want to know what kind of istinja (paper/water/other??) is allowed in Islam in the following 2 situations:

1. Situation 1: When someone is healthy/not sick.
2. Situation 2: When someone is sick.

Please provide me with quran, ahadith, or other daalil.

**UPDATE**

I once heard that istinja with paper is allowed but I never looked after the daalil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With water it is called "Istinja" and with paper, sand, or rock it's called "Istijmar".

Its allowed to use any or both (Isinija or/and istijmar), just enough to remove dirtiness.

In regards to being being sick or healthy, just use what is enough and what you are able to use. E.g: if using water painful or you have any other issue like if you had a surgery, then use paper.

It's not allowed to use any other thing for this, like bones, leaves, and dung etc.

You can see this [link](http://islamqa.info/en/cat/257) for more.

And if you understand arabic, see this [link](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=80356).